# Cannot receive notification when phone is in deep sleep mode

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver, android-wake-lock

My problem is that when my phone is in deep sleep  mode i cannot receive the push notification. i can use WAKEFULLBROADCAST RECIEVER  but it cannot awake the device when  device is in deep sleep mode. i can also write the permission in the manifest file.

```
public class GcmWakeReciver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            PushNotificationService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
}
```

Also use the wakelock code where i can build the notification.